# Preparing DNS for AD Domain Rename

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, rename

So I am currently gathering information in regards to renaming our AD domain name from company.net to company.local.

I am reading through the docs on technet.microsoft.com and It states that I would need to prepare the new DNS zones before executing the domain rename.

The question I am asking about is regarding the _msdcs subdomain

_msdcs.company.net

I have read posts of forums where people reported issues after renaming their domain and not having the _msdcs subdomain forward lookup zone. Some even reported that an _msdcs subdomain is created but inside

Obvisouly _msdcs is needed So should I create two forward lookup zones like so;

_msdcs.company.local
company.local

When the domain name rename has been executed and the DC are restarting will they auto generate all the relevent _msdcs records in the new forward lookup zone _msdcs.company.local or will I have to create them myself.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do not use .local as suffix for your internal domain, ever. .local is used for bonjour/mdns and should not be used for other purposes. Current standard practice is to use a subdomain of company.net, such as corp.company.net or ad.company.net.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the assumption that Microsoft actively encouraged you to use .local as an AD domain name. Thanks! I guess I better think of a suitable subdomain.company.net for the AD domain name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, please read [my blog post about how to name your AD](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810122929/http://www.mdmarra.com/2012/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-local-in-your.html).

Ok, so now you're hopefully ready to name your AD `ad.example.com` or `corp.example.com`. Good choice, that's very reasonable of you.

To answer your actual question, after you complete the domain rename and reboot the DCs, they will self-register everything necessary in the _msdcs zone.

A word of warning, do this in a test lab two or three times first. You only get one shot, don't screw it up!

Comment: Thanks for replying, I read your blog post and it was very informative.

Just to clarify 

So after creating the new forward lookup zones;

_msdcs.subdomain.company.net
subdomain.company.net

And rebooting the DC's they will self-register all the required records?

Comment: No. After creating those zones, **doing the domain rename as documented by microsoft**, and rebooting, you will see those zones begin to populate.

Comment: @MDMarra - You do get more than one shot at this. Once you've done the `rendom /clean` you're free to rename the domain again. It would be silly, but you can do it.